# Qual(is) problemas terei em utilizar o ob_start() e ob_end_flush()?

Tags: php, session

Minha aplicação é um site pra uma imobiliária e estou com problemas em um recurso desenvolvido com session semelhante a um carrinho de compra pra adicionar mais de um imóvel em uma única proposta. O problema que esta acontecendo, é que quando selecionado um imóvel é criado a sessão porém, tem vezes que o imóvel aparece na lista de pedidos e tem vezes que não, e tem vezes que só aparece depois um certo tempo(delay).

Esse problema pode esta relacionado ao ob_start() e end_flush()? Alguém poderia me dá alguma sugestão do que pode esta acontecendo?

Minha aplicação esta dessa forma:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require('includes/paginator.class.php');
    require('includes/cookie.class.php');  
    require('config/get.php');
    require('config/config.php');
    require_once ('includes/recaptchalib.php');
    require_once('classes/Conexao.php');
    require_once('classes/Carrinho.php');

    <conteúdo estatico head>

<conteúdo estatico header>

    <conteúdo dinamico com includes das páginas(contato/institucional/pedido/etc)>

    <conteúdo estático footer>
    end_flush();
    ?>
```

Comment: Quando você usa `ob_start();` e `end_flush();` você está dizendo que o conteúdo HTML será impresso entre esses dois elementos, você não deve  colocar os requires de classes, conexão, e config etc. dentro dessas regras, nem o `session_start();`.

Comment: Se compreendi bem, todo ob_start(); e session_start(); deve ficar depois dos includes e require? Geralmente o pessoal fala que eles deve ficar antes de tudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você usa `ob_start();` e `end_flush();` Você está carregando um buffer de um conteúdo. Não recomendo que você coloque as requisições de classes, conexão, e de config dentro dessas funções, para isso, você pode usar o `session_start();` ou `setcookie()`.

No seu caso, acredito que poderia resolver seu problema fazendo algo do tipo:

```
<?php
session_start();
require('includes/paginator.class.php');
require('includes/cookie.class.php');  
require('config/get.php');
require('config/config.php');
require_once('includes/recaptchalib.php');
require_once('classes/Conexao.php');
require_once('classes/Carrinho.php');

if (session_id() == '') {
   echo "A sessão expirou!";
   die();
}

echo getTemplate('arquivo_externo');

  function getTemplate($file) {
      ob_start();
      include $file.'.php';
      $template = ob_get_contents(); 
      ob_end_clean();
      return $template;
      end_flush();
  }
```

Comment: Obrigado Ivan, vou fazer um teste com o exemplo da sua resposta.

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo melhorado disso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061032/php-file-get-contents-with-php-intact

Comment: Ivan, se eu estiver com a session iniciada no arquivo principal(index.php), e depois setar outras session em arquivos secundários como na páginas incluidas, eu posso ter problemas em repetir a session_start() varias vezes?

Comment: Na verdade você tem que setar o `session_start()` no topo do seu arquivo principal de config que irá tratar as demais páginas que houver sessão. Não precisa colocar isso em todos os includes, basta colocar no primeiro include que irá ser carregado em todas as páginas que precisa ter sessão.

Answer (score 1):

Meu problema não era exatamente com o ob_start(), e sim o cache do servidor. Estou hospedando na kinghost com o servidor de cache varnish ativo o que bugou totalmente minha aplicação, pelo simples fato desse servidor esta armazenando as sessoes e os cookies e não na maquina do usuário, após desativação do servidor de cache tudo voltou ao normal.

Agradeço pelas respostas. Problema solucionado.