# o que exatamente faz o ob_start();

Tags: php

Boa tarde a todos!!
Pessoal, andei estudando essa função ob_start(); mas não ficou claro o que ela faz exatamente...sei que melhora o desempenho da página, porém de que forma especificamente?
"Pilhar" essa função em uma página com conteúdo maior ajuda?
Obrigado pela atenção!!

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191839/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90069/101

Comment: "sei que melhora o desempenho da página" na verdade tá mais pra "não sei", pq isso não é verdade. Depende de como usa.

Comment: @Bacco justamente o contrário. Se ela armazena em memória a saída do arquivo, provavelmente vai aumentar o consumo da memória e processamento do lado do servidor.